# Spring boot not running on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

So I have a spring boot application build with Gradle.
It's working just fine when build and run locally, however, I can't make it run on Heroku. Here are the logs:

```
2018-03-10T22:24:19.561282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=53342 $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar`
2018-03-10T22:24:21.446741+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2018-03-10T22:24:21.458097+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-03-10T22:24:21.461370+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701767+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701779+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701781+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701783+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701784+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701786+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701788+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701789+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701792+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701791+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701794+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.bristech.BristechApp.main(BristechApp.java:12)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701795+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 8 more
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701797+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701798+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701800+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701802+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701804+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2018-03-10T22:24:21.701805+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 9 more
2018-03-10T22:24:21.828827+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-10T22:24:21.845444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-10T22:24:21.848108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-10T22:24:24.295261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=48859 $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar`
2018-03-10T22:24:25.862214+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-03-10T22:24:25.849109+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2018-03-10T22:24:25.865381+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2018-03-10T22:24:26.065973+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066210+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066306+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066354+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066402+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066464+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066593+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066532+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066651+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066845+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
2018-03-10T22:24:26.067057+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066918+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.bristech.BristechApp.main(BristechApp.java:12)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.066974+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 8 more
2018-03-10T22:24:26.067098+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.067138+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.067221+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.067225+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2018-03-10T22:24:26.067285+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 9 more
2018-03-10T22:24:26.176301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-10T22:24:26.195791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-10T22:35:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:36:30.552290+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:36:30.552290+00:00 app[api]: Deploy eb0b8be4 by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:35:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-03-10T22:36:31.291066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-10T22:36:34.505370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar build/libs/bristech.jar`
2018-03-10T22:36:36.916160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-10T22:36:36.918820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-10T22:36:36.899817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-10T22:36:36.830058+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-03-10T22:36:36.831354+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/bristech.jar
2018-03-10T22:36:39.908150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar build/libs/bristech.jar`
2018-03-10T22:36:41.758247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-10T22:36:41.698096+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-03-10T22:36:41.700091+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/bristech.jar
2018-03-10T22:36:41.771761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-10T22:40:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:41:11.017941+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a7465293 by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:41:11.017941+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:40:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-03-10T22:41:11.805609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-10T22:41:14.238089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar build/libs/bristech_server.jar`
2018-03-10T22:41:15.655343+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-03-10T22:41:15.656220+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/bristech_server.jar
2018-03-10T22:41:15.712848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-10T22:41:15.693130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-10T22:42:07.343849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bristech-server.herokuapp.com request_id=807880ea-219e-425b-88dc-0265c5800c3b fwd="77.101.215.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=h
ttps
2018-03-10T22:42:07.948730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bristech-server.herokuapp.com request_id=2928b2e5-6133-454b-ba6a-5809755f0329 fwd="77.101.215.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 protocol=https
2018-03-10T22:42:11.097608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/users/1" host=bristech-server.herokuapp.com request_id=d158abb8-e7b3-4dfd-a889-8cf575eec7c0 fwd="77.101.215.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= pro
tocol=https
2018-03-10T22:42:11.379526+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bristech-server.herokuapp.com request_id=8e403565-3112-4a5a-8329-70883b0eb68a fwd="77.101.215.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 protocol=https
2018-03-10T22:42:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:43:02.996084+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f76796c1 by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:43:02.996084+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user bris47degrees@gmail.com
2018-03-10T22:42:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-03-10T22:43:03.470870+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-03-10T22:43:05.898870+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar build/libs/bristech.jar`
2018-03-10T22:43:07.244601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-03-10T22:43:07.194950+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-03-10T22:43:07.195870+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/bristech.jar
2018-03-10T22:43:07.258778+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've got this Procfile:

```
web: java -jar build/libs/bristech.jar
```

and this is my gradle.build:

```
group 'com.bristech'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'bristech'
}

task stage {
    dependsOn build
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    //Spring web, database and security
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.9.0'

    //logging
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.10.0")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I suspect that the error has to to with the jar file. I've tried running it without a Procfile too, however it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think by running locally, you mean running from target folder. copy the jar somewhere else and run, I suspect this wont work because the jar does not have required dependencies (hence class not found exception). If you see this is the issue, try creating fat jar using spring boot plugin.

Comment: @bestwishes by running locally I mean that I can build it as it is with IntelliJ, however when I push it to Heroku, it doesn't build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was in my gradle.build file.
I'm using `implementation` to add new dependencies instead of `compile`. 
As soon as I changed it worked like a charm...

I thought that `implementation` was the new version of compile and it was going to replace it..

Answer (score 1):

You should specify jar name with version in your Procfile like below.

`web: java -jar build/libs/bristech-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Still the same. I don't think this is the problem, it's just not recognising the classes somehow.